# How to compute the integer m such that m^3 <= Long.MAX_VALUE < (m + 1)^3 by Java language?

Tags: java, overflow, long-integer

I want to know the `long m` such that `m*m*m <= Long.MAX_VALUE && Long.MAX_VALUE < (m + 1)*(m + 1)*(m + 1)`.

How can I compute the above `long m`?

I am worried about overflow and I don't know about overflow at all.

Comment: This looks more like a [math problem](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=m%5E3+%3C%3D+(2%5E63)-1+%3C+(m%2B1)%5E3) to me.

Comment: `Long.MAX_VALUE == (2^63)-1`. If `m == 2^(63/3) = 2^21`, then `m*m*m = 2^63`. So, `(m+1) == 2^21`, and hence `m == (2^21)-1`.

Comment: if `Long.MAX_VALUE < (m + 1)*(m + 1)*(m + 1)` you can't calculate it directly using long. You can how ever find  `Math.cbrt(Long.MAX_VALUE)`

Comment: @c0der I am afraid of an error when I use Math.cbrt() function.

Comment: @tchappyha do you mean accuracy error ? or java error ?

Comment: I mean accuracy error.

Comment: I didn't want to use floating point number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need Java to solve this.

`Long.MAX_VALUE == (2^63)-1`. If `n == 2^(63/3) = 2^21`, then `n*n*n = 2^63`. So, `(m+1) == 2^21`, and hence `m == (2^21)-1`.

If you want to write some code to convince yourself of this:

```
    long m = (1L << 21) - 1;
    System.out.println(m*m*m);                  // 9223358842721533951
    System.out.println(m*m*m < Long.MAX_VALUE); // true

    long n = m + 1;
    System.out.println(n*n*n);                  // -9223372036854775808
```

So `n*n*n` has obviously overflowed, because its value is negative.

(Note that if the result were positive, or even greater than `m*m*m`, this wouldn't be evidence that it *hadn't* overflowed. It's just coincidence that the overflow is so apparent).

You can also use [`Long.compareUnsigned`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#compareUnsigned-long-long-):

```
// Negative, so m*m*m < Long.MAX_VALUE)
System.out.println(Long.compareUnsigned(m*m*m, Long.MAX_VALUE));

// Positive, so unsigned n*n*n > Long.MAX_VALUE)
System.out.println(Long.compareUnsigned(n*n*n, Long.MAX_VALUE));
```

Comment: `n*n*n == Long.MAX_VALUE` ,  not as requested.

Comment: @c0der `n*n*n == 9223372036854775808`, which is greater than `Long.MAX_VALUE == 9223372036854775807`. https://ideone.com/9lzfNT

Comment: `double n = m + 1;
     System.out.println(n*n*n == Long.MAX_VALUE);`  prints true.  Is this test wrong ?

Comment: @c0der yes. Double doesn't have enough precision to distinguish (max value) and (max value + 1). http://ideone.com/2b5yOm

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, c0der.

I can use `Math.cbrt()` function to get the answer.
And I can check the answer is right by Andy Turner's method.

`long m1 = (long) Math.cbrt((double) Long.MAX_VALUE);
System.out.println(m1*m1*m1);
m1++;
System.out.println(m1*m1*m1);`

Comment: `m1*m1*m1  == Long.MAX_VALUE` which is not what you are looking for.  This printout `System.out.println(m1*m1*m1);` overflows.

Answer (score 0):

Is this ok?

```
long i = 0, j = 1;
while (i*i*i < j*j*j) {
    i++;
    j++;
}
Sytem.out.println(i);
```